# Returning sum of added values from 1 and n only if that value is not divisible by 3 or 5

Tags: javascript, algorithm

This question has 2 test cases, the inputs of 10 & 15.

```
function threesFives(num){
   var sum = 0;

   for(let i = 1; num >= i; i++){
      if (i % 3 == 0 || i % 5 == 0){
        sum += i;
      }
   }
   return sum 
}
```

I don't see why only Test case 2 (input of 15) is passed, but Test Case 1 is not (gives me a sum of 33, which needs to be 22).

Comment: Testing that function with `10` outputs `33` and it is correct. 3+5+6+9+10 = 33

Comment: Whatever you're doing with the inputs, the code is expected to return 33 as mentioned by @LouysPatriceBessette. Please provide the entire question to understand what are you trying to achieve.

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette, I believe it's the opposite , The OP says "Returning sum of added values from 1 and n only if that value is **NOT** divisible by 3 or 5". So it should be 1 + 2 + 4 + 7 + 8 = 22

Comment: Ho!!! Nice catch @SamuelAnyanwu !! ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You say "Return sum of added values from 1 and n only if that value is not divisible by 3 or 5". So if the number is divisible by 3 or 5, you skip it in the loop. You're doing the opposite right now. Your code passes the first case by pure coincidence

Your code should be somewhat like this

```js
function threesFives(num){
   var sum = 0;

   for(let i = 1; num >= i; i++){
      if (i % 3 == 0 || i % 5 == 0){
        continue;
      }
     sum += i;
   }
  
   return sum 
}

console.log(threesFives(10))
```

Comment: Makes sense, thank you. 1 passed test case just confused me more than it should've.

Answer (score 0):

Since you need to sum only those values that are not divisible by both 3 and 5, the condition in if statement should have been an AND && condition instead of an OR || one.

Comment: With the `&&` operator and `10` as the `num`, the function would output `0`... Not `22`. So... OP's problem is elsewhere.

Comment: My bad. I probably missed completing it. It should have been an AND with a !== in place of the ==